# How to add, update and delete row from table dynamically in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in reactJS.

Here, I make a file in which I have made a form and table.

I have added some static data in to the table already. But, I want to add, update and delete rows dynamically.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code In which the insert, update and delete function are there. 
What will be the correct code for that? Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Product.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        category: '',
        price: '',
        formErrors: ''
    }

    handleUserInputs = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    insertHandler = (e) => {

        if (this.state.name === '' || this.state.name === null) {
            this.setState({ formErrors: 'Blank Name' });
        }
        else if ((this.state.category === '' || this.state.category === null)) {
            this.setState({ formErrors: 'Blank Category' });
        }
        else if (this.state.price === '' || this.state.price === null || typeof this.state.price === 'undefined') {
            this.setState({ formErrors: 'Blank Price' });
        }
        else if (!this.state.price.match(/^[0-9\b]+$/)) {
            this.setState({ formErrors: 'Price should be in digits only.' });
        }
        else {
            // insert code will be here
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    editHandler = (e) => {        
        // update code will be here
    }
    deleteHandler = (e) => {        
        // delete row code will be here.
    }

    render() {
        const data = [
            {   "id": 1,             
                "name": "Chips",
                "category": "Food",
                "price": "20"               
            },
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "name": "Shirt",
                "category": "Clothes",
                "price": "500"   
            },
            {
                "id": 3, 
                "name": "Mobile",
                "category": "Electronics",
                "price": "10000"   
            }
          ];

        return (
            <div className={classes.main}>
                <div className={classes.Product}>
                    <div className={classes.product_box_body}>
                        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <h2>Add Product</h2>
                            <div className={classes.name}>
                                <input type="text" name="name" className={classes.form_control} placeholder="Product Name" value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleUserInputs(e)} />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.category}>
                                <select className={classes.form_control} name="category" onChange={(e) => this.handleUserInputs(e)} aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="">-- Select any Category --</option>
                                    <option value="Food">Food</option>
                                    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                                    <option value="Clothes">Clothes</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.price}>
                                <input type="text" name="price" className={classes.form_control} placeholder="Price" value={this.state.price} onChange={(e) => this.handleUserInputs(e)} />
                            </div>
                            <p className={classes.text_red}>{this.state.formErrors}</p> 
                            <button type="submit" className={classes.product} onClick={(e) => this.insertHandler(e)}>Insert</button>
                            <Link to="/login" className={classes.cancel}>Cancel</Link>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table className={classes.table}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Name</th>
                                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Category</th>
                                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Price</th>
                                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {data.map(obj => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                <td style={{width: '50px'}}>
                                    {obj.name}
                                </td>
                                <td style={{width: '50px'}}>
                                    {obj.category}
                                </td>
                                <td style={{width: '50px'}}>
                                    {obj.price}
                                </td>
                                <td style={{width: '120px'}}>
                                    <button type="submit" name="Edit" value="edit" onClick={(e) => this.editHandler(e)}>Edit</button> <button type="submit" name="Delete" value="delete" onClick={(e) => this.deleteHandler(e)}>Delete</button>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                            })}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to manage your array data in the state, you need :
state={data=[]} and then your delete function erase data of you array and then you need to call the method setState who render de component with the new data merge and the same to update , you modify your array data and later call setState and magic happend, you can asing your data to state in the constructor o componentDidMount method